# GET requests to https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2 methods return HTTP 400 "Violation of backoff parameter" without previously warning to back off

Tags: feature-request, api, rate-limiting, throttling

We have the following logic to make [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) requests to *https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2*:

```
  private async get(
    apiMethod: string, // can be 'users', 'tags', 'info', or 'questions'
    url: string, // prefixed with https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/
    searchParams: undefined | { [k: string]: string | number | undefined }
  ): Promise<unknown> {
    await this.waitUntilRateLimiterAllowsCall(apiMethod);

    let response;
    try {
      response = await this.fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: this.headers,
        searchParams,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      Log.warn(e, {
        meta: 'Stack Overflow GET errored',
        apiMethod,
      });
      throw e;
    }

    if (response.backoff != null) {
      // If backoff is provided, we need to wait this many seconds before
      // calling the same endpoint again
      Log.info('Backing off Stack Overflow method', {
        apiMethod,
        backoffSeconds: response.backoff,
      });

      // backoff for an extra 2 seconds to give Stack Overflow some room to breathe, backing off for response.backoff or response.backoff + 1 kept getting us throttled
      await this.rateLimiterBackoffStackOverflow(
        apiMethod,
        response.backoff + 2
      );
    }

    return response;
  }
```

The implementation of `waitUntilRateLimiterAllowsCall` looks like this:

```
  async waitUntilRateLimiterAllowsCall(
    apiMethod: string | undefined, // can be 'users', 'tags', 'info', or 'questions'
  ): Promise<void> {
    const callCost = 1;

    // Remove from our burst allowance first, which is 30 calls per 5 seconds to stay safely away from the Stack Overflow abusive burst limit of 30 requests in 1 second
    await this.removeTokens('stackOverflowBurst', callCost, /* limitKey */ undefined);

    // Once we've passed our burst allowance we can eat away at our "main call" limit of 10k calls per day
    await this.removeTokens('stackOverflow', callCost, /* limitKey */ undefined);

    // Check if apiMethod has been blocked due to a backoff result
    await this.removeTokens('stackOverflowMethod', callCost, apiMethod);
  }
```

`this.fetch` is a call to a tiny wrapper around the `got` library https://www.npmjs.com/package/got

```
export const fetch = async (
  url: string,
  args: HttpFetcherArgs
): Promise<Record<string, unknown>> => {
  const req = got(url, args);

  return (await req.json()) as Record<string, unknown>;
};
```

These GET requests can be made by up to five processes running in parallel, and we manage the rate-limiting via [Redis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis_%28data_store%29) with *[node-rate-limiter-flexible](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible)*.

We have evidence of both the `Log.warn` and `Log.info` message being logged + queryable in Cloudwatch:

In the first screenshot here we show that we receive + log the `Backing off Stack Overflow method` events.

[image: Evidence of Log.info on backoff]

In the second screenshot here, we see a flurry of `Stack Overflow GET errored` warns with no `Backing off Stack Overflow method` logs in the previous ~50 minutes, which suggests that api.stackexchange.com is throttling us due to "Violation of backoff parameter" without first warning us to back off.

[image: Evidence of Log.warn during throttle, with no matching Log.info for backoff]

Aside, we tried to be diligent and check that we're not violating other throttling parameters. We're confident we're below the 10k daily request rate limit:

[image: Fewer than 6k requests in the 24 hours leading up to this period of throttled requests]

1. Does the code snippet look right to you?
2. Are you aware of a possible bug that could be throttling without warning? Hypothetical: an ordering bug where we make a request that **would have** resulted in Stack Exchange replying with a `backoff` field, and we issue a second request in parallel => both requests 400 with this "Violation of backoff parameter" error without us ever receiving the `backoff` field.
3. Is there correct behaviour that we can build here without being told to backoff? While searching for previous answers I found [Include backoff value (or remaining time) in API backoff violation response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256691), would you reconsider that request and include the backoff in the throttle response so we know how long to back off for when we get throttled?

Comment: Looking at the logs I wonder if you're not violating the request limit: *Every application is subject to an IP based concurrent request throttle. If a single IP is making more than 30 requests a second, new requests will be dropped. The exact ban period is subject to change, but will be on the order of 30 seconds to a few minutes typically. Note that exactly what response an application gets (in terms of HTTP code, text, and so on) is undefined when subject to this ban; we consider > 30 request/sec per IP to be very abusive and thus cut the requests off very harshly.*

Comment: If you hit that limit, you'll not get a backoff because the application never served your call so it didn't had to do any bookkeeping for a backoff now or in the future. https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle

Comment: Are you *sure* that this application is the *only* thing making requests from that public IP address? Unless you have this application as the *only* thing from that IP address, then the `backoff` could easily have been sent in response to some request by a different application/browser/browser tab/userscript/whatever.

Comment: On an off-note, last time I checked, `backoff` is either present or not and is never equal to `null`. Am I missing something? Unless `this.fetch` is a custom implementation, of course

Comment: I also do not see anything in the snippet that sets the `result.backoff` property - can this be the typo why you are getting rate-limited?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I assumed it was JavaScript, with `response` set to `await this.fetch()`, which presumably results in `response` set to the decoded JSON Object. So, `response.backoff` will be `undefined` most of the time, which would make `response.backoff != null` false, as it uses `!=` rather than `!==`.

Comment: @rene
> I wonder if you're not violating the request limit
If we are, I'd expect to see a different error message from "Violation of backoff parameter" which implies specifically that we were told to backoff, not that we're over the request limit. Still, our rate limiter should prevent this. I've updated my original post to show how `waitUntilRateLimiterAllowsCall` is implemented.

Comment: @Makyen
> Are you _sure_ that this application is the _only_ thing making requests from that public IP address?
I grep'd our codebase, I can't see anything speaking to api.stackexchange.com except this method.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine, Makyen is correct about the absence of `backoff` resulting in the `response.backoff` access returning `undefined` and failing the `!= null` check. Also, the first screenshot provides evidence that when `backoff` is present, we log the message that we expect to see.

Comment: The short answer is that, yes, this can happen, particularly when you have more than one request in flight at a time (e.g. one may or may not get a `backoff` and the others may just get an error). You won't have an accurate view of the conditions under which it's happening without logging every request (both upon start and end). Once it happens, you should stop making requests for a period of time (10, 15 or 30 seconds is usually sufficient, but it's sometimes minutes). I'd note that SE doesn't consider this behavior to be a bug. IIRC, there are other questions asking about similar behavior.

Comment: @RafBlecher the part about `!== null` was just an off-note in case it might help - so I assume the `response` object is set to the result of `await fetch_response.json()`? I am more worried about the `result.backoff` - can you show where this property is set?

Comment: If this is not considered a bug, can we revisit putting the `backoff` field in the 502 "Violation of backoff parameter" response so we don't have to guess how long we have to back off for? "30 seconds is usually sufficient, but it's sometimes minutes" is a little vague to build on top of. For now, I'll put in a 30 second rate limiter block when we get this 502

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I've added the implementation of `this.fetch` to my post

Comment: @RafBlecher I see, O.K., that part is clear to me now. Can you clarify what exactly is `result.backoff` and how is it set? I do not see neither where it is declared nor where the `backoff` property is set on it. Is it a typo? If so, should it not be `response.backoff + 2`?

Comment: Ohhh I see, I'm sorry, I modified this code snippet to remove a call to some JSON validation that we're doing hence the `response`/`result` name mismatch -- I'll update the code example, `result.backoff` should be `response.backoff`

Comment: @RafBlecher that makes more sense now :) With that out of the way, it's most likely what Makyen said above - unfortunately, SE does not consider this behavior an issue. Inasmuch as we would love to get the https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256691/786798 implemented, it seems like it is a cold case, at least for now. SE hasn't done anything for the API (Collectives *do not count!*) in a long time...

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the API end point sits behind the HA-proxy as well. That error response might come directly from HA-proxy throttling settings and for obvious reasons the HA-proxy has no knowledge about the backoff parameter or how long it expects you have to wait as those throttles are dynamic.

Comment: I should also note that there are multiple error responses which the SE API may give. Basically all of them mean that you should backoff and wait. There is no all inclusive list and the SE API specifically doesn't specify what all of them are, or might be in the future. As rene has mentioned, there are multiple layers to how SE handles requests and the errors may be generated and returned from various ones. You just need to handle them. Effectively, if it's not an error which indicates there's actually something wrong with the request, then you should assume that it means to backoff.

Comment: After a backoff/error of any sort, I've found it's a good idea to try single, non-overlapping requests at substantial intervals (at least tens of seconds) until you start getting valid responses again, then slowly ramp up to your normal rate. In addition to the above, there are quota blocks, which result in having to wait up to 24 hours. There are also full IP blocks, which may be in place for any amount of time from seconds to minutes to hours. If it goes for multiple hours, you can contact SE. We had to do that a few times as SE had misconfigured things such that the blocks never ended.